# MongoDB: How to determine intersection of GeoJson LineString and a Point with radius

Tags: mongodb, geospatial

How to determine in MongoDB using geospatial query, if a circle determined by a Point and radius, intersects with LineString?

Usecase:

MongoDB GeoJson LineString Object defined as below:

```
db.places.insert(
{
    loc : { type: "LineString", coordinates: [ [-121.9420624, 37.3734995], [ -121.9388008, 37.3755458], [-121.9408607, 37.3720671] ] },
    name: "Small trail"
});
```

User location is [ -121.928887, 37.299849 ]
How to determine if a circle with User location as center, and radius as 10 mile, intersect the LineString anywhere?

I was expecting a query something like

```
db.places.find({loc : {$geoIntersects :{$geometry :{$centerSphere: [ [ -121.928887, 37.299849 ], 100 / 3959 ]}}}});
```

But this one does not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation is confusing, but I think the bottom line is that `$geoIntersects` doesn't work with `$centerSphere`. `$centerSphere` does work with `$geoWithin`, though. Does that work for your use case? The semantics are a bit different but may be close enough.

Comment: @NitinSingh The docs say for `$geoWithin` "Selects documents with geospatial data that exists entirely within a specified shape." Did this actually work even when the line isn't entirely in the circle? Can you also query vice versa (find the circles given line path)?